# Ember view rerenders on receiving update

Tags: ember.js

I'm creating a real time app in Ember.

Every time I receive an update I do the following:

```
 record = serializer.extractSingle(store, type, data);
 store.update(socketModel, record);
```

The update is an `drawnNumbers` array.

This happens in my view;

```
{{#each bingoCard in ownBingoCards}}
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <span class="label label-primary">Card {{bingoCard.id}}</span>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-card">
                <tbody>
                {{#each row in bingoCard.squares}}
                <tr>
                    {{#each number in row itemController='number'}}
                    {{#if number}}
                    <td {{bind-attr class='isActive:active'}}>{{number.model}}</td>
                    {{else}}
                    <td>X</td>
                    {{/if}}
                    {{/each}}
                </tr>
                {{/each}}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

`ownBingoCards` is a computed property

```
ownBingoCards: function () {
    var gameId, userId;
    gameId = this.get('id');
    userId = this.get('session.content.id');

    return this.get('store').filter('bingoCard', function (bingoCard) {
        return (bingoCard.get('game.id') === gameId && bingoCard.get('user.id') === userId);
    });
}.property('model.bingoCards', 'session.content'),
```

So everytime a number gets added to the `drawnNumbers` array it's setting that `td` to `active`.

The only problem is, my whole view rerenders make it very laggy. But as soon as I refresh my browser it stops rerendering the whole view and just marking the numbers `active`. Why does this happen? Why is this refresh needed?

Comment: My guess would be that it's blasting away and recreating the entire `numbers` collection, which would make ember need to re-render that collection in it's entirety.  How many numbers are there, and how many bound data points are in each of them?

Comment: The array starts empty `[]` and then receives a new number everytime like this: `[1]` `[1,5]` `[1,5,60]` `[1,5,60,50]` up to 75 numbers.
As soon as it receives the first number it keeps rerendering the whole view. Until I do a browser refresh then I never rerenders again in that view

Comment: I just found out the problem only existing in the computed property `ownBingoCard` I've updated my post

Comment: And I found out the exact problem. Before the refresh the `ownBingoCards` property gets called everytime the `drawnNumbers` array is updated. After the refresh it's gone

Comment: maybe you just said this, but when you create a filter it is long living, so each time you hit the property you create a new filter, so slowly you end up having a slew of filters each one iterating over the entire list and updating their list of records.  This would be considered an unintentional memory leak.

Comment: But what I don't understand is when I call store.update with this record `drawnNumbers: [1]
id: "5388d27c5acb2852420e20b1"` why the `ownBingoCards` property gets called. And when I refresh my browser it doesn't get called anymore.

Comment: it should get called at least once, did you toss a debugger statement into it?

Comment: Yes after a refresh it calls it once upon loading and then never again.